# Is it possible to compile java with gcc on eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, gcc

I heard that one of the best ways to protect your java code is to compile it to specific hardware using gcc. This would not be a problem to me, as I want to build for a specific platform.

Having that said, is it possible to configure eclipse to use GCC to compile java code when building binaries?

Comment: GCJ is the preferred way to compile Java classes instead of GCC (in lieu of javac).  Since I don't think that's what you want (it'll just compile it straight across), why not look into obfuscation instead?

Comment: [Recent developments](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTUwOTA) suggest that GCJ is sidling towards obsolescence.

Comment: Doing this loses one of the greatest benefits of coding in Java - platform-independence. You now have to maintain a build for all architectures you wish to support, which complicates your build and deployment processes. Make sure you ask yourself if those costs are worth the benefit you get. As Makoto pointed out, perhaps look into obfuscation instead, e.g. http://proguard.sourceforge.net/ (which comes with its own set of complications). "I heard that" suggests this is a relatively new concept for you, which raises a red flag suggesting you may not be in a good position to make this decision.

Answer (score 0):

[Maybe](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fgcj.html). I believe Ubuntu and Debian ship an eclipse compiled with gcj.